# I can't figure out how to call a variable from another method

Tags: variables, call

I am am trying to call a variable in another method to my array.
var Com = the difficulty for the game. But the method below I'm trying to call the var Com, for: var c = Com.GetChoice();

Not sure why I can not figure out how to call it.

```
public object SetDiff()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter difficulty #: (1 = Easy, 2 = Normal, 3 = Impossible)");
            var diff = Console.ReadLine();
            int mode;
            int.TryParse(diff, out mode);

            if (mode == 1)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                var Com = new Easy();
                return Com;
            }
            if (mode == 2)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                var Com = new Medium();
                return Com;
            }
            if (mode == 3)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                var Com = new Hard();
                return Com;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid input.");
                return SetDiff();
            }
        } // Apparently you can't set variables in a switch.

        public int[] FaceOff(int num)
        {
            int PlayerWin = 0;
            int ComWin = 0;
            int Tie = num + 1;
            // TODO : Get rid of TIES! 
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                var p = p1.GetChoice();
                var c = Com.GetChoice();
```

Comment: variable Com does not exist in the current context, is the error it gives me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please get yourself familiar with variable scope: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many different options:

**Pass as parameter**

```
 public int[] FaceOff(int num, int Com){...}
```

**make a "global" variable**

```
private int Com;
```

I would also recommend you to learn OOP (Object Orientated Programming) basics.